# Unity Blury Animation How To Fix?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile game and when I'm running that game on unity  the player looks blury   [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/49750a9354b8f472ce7ebe67dcb7dd4e) and very rough it's suppose to look smooth and crisp  but when I run my game on mobile it looks super nice and there isn't a blur how could I fix this problem?

heres my inspecter for my sprite ***what I tried and didnt work was I changed the pxiel per unit to 16 and  changed the filer mode to point (no filter *** but when I apply those  nothing changes the images will still look blury when I run it and I'm not sure what the problem is
any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: What is the canvas size of your textures?

Comment: I'm fairly new to unity are you saying the size of my player [size](https://gyazo.com/6c8527dfe4edff5f85f3e801a8fc95d8) here

Comment: Sorry - what is the original size of your image outside of Unity, the dimensions.

Comment: they are all by 739 x 369

Comment: sorry for being impatient  but do you have a answer?

Comment: I am actually not too sure what could cause it. If the sprite looks fine in-game but not in engine, it is not a real issue. It potentially could be something to do with compression, but it does not look like you have any compression on the images. You also do not have mipmapping enabled and you are using point as your filter, which should result in more crisp pixel art. What kind of Canvas are you using? Or is this a sprite you are using?

Comment: [image](https://gyazo.com/3f31adc439bdb11e332ad94d5f32daa9) it's the sprite everything is fine but just the sprite no matter what I change it will keep looking blury like that

Comment: Is it a huge issue if it looks incorrect in engine? If it looks fine in a mobile build which is your target platform, I do not really see a huge issue here.

Comment: its a bit of problem because I want to record on computer but if I record on phone the screen will be smaller and this is a big problem for me. *Video recording

Comment: Possibly try changing the alpha source? I'll need to try this myself as I have never gotten results as you're experiencing. Generally anything in engine is the same as build from what I've seen.

Comment: nope still no results do you want to discord call and maybe see?

Comment: Did you perhaps accidentally zoom in a bit in the editor? That can cause blurring. Try ensure the game window is zoomed completely out.

Comment: It's zoomed out still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the game view to "fixed resolution" instead of "aspect ratio".
2. Choose a standard resolution, like 720x1280.
3. Make sure game view is set to 1x magnification with the slider.